# Grep: begin with string1, end with first occurence of string2

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to parse an HTML file, containing several http links.
I want to get a BIG line beginning with a specific string, and ending with another specific string, but I can't know what is between the two strings, so here is my problem: if I use grep like this:

```
grep -E -o 'string1.+string2'
```

I get a big line corresponding to the regexp, but it is ending with the LAST occurence of 'string2', because of the '.+'.
Actually, I want it to end at the FIRST occurence of 'string2', so I tried:

```
grep -E -o 'string1[^(string2)]+string2'
```

But it doesn't work either, I get the same result :( ...

How can I tell grep to match a line starting with 'string1' and ending at the first occurence of 'string2' ?

Thank you for reading me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` operator is being "greedy" any eating up all of the characters it can (including `string2`). You can make it not greedy by adding a `?` (this is only supported when `perl` matching is enabled, therefore the `-P` flag):

```
grep -P -o 'string1.+?string2
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but the way I read OP's question I would think you'd need to anchor this on `^`.

Comment: It works just fine ! Thank you very mych, I have been trying countless ways to do it... in fact it was pretty simple ^^

Comment: @kojiro The OP has the `-o` flag, therefore it would only output the part of the line that was matched.

Comment: @PlasmaPower that doesn't really have to do with it being anchored or not. My point was that it could match a line where string1 wasn't at the start of the line.

Comment: @kojiro Yes, but only the part wanted would be outputted. @user3451029 do you want this to match a line that is something like `blah string1 blah string2`?

Comment: Well, I wanted to print the part of a (very long) line, that part beginning with string 1, etc... The (very long) line itself could begin with no matter what. So I didn't need anchor here :)

Answer (score 0):

Some over complicated `awk`s

```
cat file
this is a test string1 get this data string2 but not this string2 end here
```

```
awk -F"string" '{split($3,a," ");print FS $2 FS a[1]}' file
string1 get this data string2
```

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i=="string1") f=1;if (f) printf $i FS; if ($i=="string2") f=0}print ""}' file
string1 get this data string2
```

It would be nice to see a simpler version :)

Comment: Over complicated `awk`s are always fun! :) In this case, regexp is probably the way to go. Also, this will print an extra field separator at the end.